# Can you use multiple message domains in boost::locale?

Tags: c++, boost, internationalization, locale, boost-locale

I have a number of applications that share a number of general libraries. I am trying to internationalize my applications using boost::locale. It will be easy for me to create a separate .mo file for each general library and for each specific application. I was wandering if it is possible to simultaneously use multiple message domains like this:

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
gen.add_messages_path(".");
gen.add_messages_domain("lib1");
gen.add_messages_domain("lib2");

std::locale::global(gen("zh_CN.UTF-8"));

.
.
.

boost::locale::gettext("Show image");
```

I was expecting boost::locale to search in both lib1.mo and lib2.mo, however this doesn't seem to work. Only messages from the first domain added are found, in this case from lib1.mo. If I add lib2 before lib1, then only messages from lib2 are found.

I know you can use a domain explicitly in the call like this:

```
boost::locale::dgettext("lib2", "Show image");
```

This does work, but I would like to avoid specifying the domain for every call. I am also not sure that this will work well with extracting the strings with xgettext.

Is it possible what I am trying to do? Am I missing something?

Please suggest any alternative if you know one.

I use msvc 9.0 (2008) and boost 1.48.

Answer (score 0):

Since there were no answers posted to this question I assume that this is not possible with boost::locale. I will shortly therefore outline what I did to achieve my required functionality:

I created a singleton class with the following interface

```
class MY_GETTEXT
{
public:

    void SetPath(const std::string& i_path);
    void AddDomain(const std::string& i_domain);
    void ChangeLocale(const std::string& i_locale);
    std::string gettext(const std::string i_msg_id);
};
```

AddDomain is called for each domain you want to use, and adds it to a member set m_language_domains_a. ChangeLocale does some locale manipulation and stores a locale in the member m_locale, I will ignore its implementation here.

To translate you should simply call MY_GETTEXT::gettext. Its implementation looks like this:

```
std::string MY_GETTEXT::gettext(const std::string i_msg_id)
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(const std::string& domain , m_language_domains_a)
    {
        if (boost::locale::translate(i_msg_id).str(m_locale, domain) != i_msg_id)
        {
            return boost::locale::translate(i_msg_id).str(m_locale, domain);
        }
    }

    return i_msg_id;
}
```